# bug in php when check mail

Tags: php, function, filter

i have this function

```
function filtermail($email){
if(filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $mail2 = explode('www.',$email);
    if(isset($mail2[1])){
        return 'false2';
    }
    else{
        return true;
    }
}
else{
    return false;
}
}
```

but when i give big.ma3ih@gmail.com to it
its return "1"!
and this code run

```
if($checkmail == 'false2'){
        echo 'ایمیل www ندارد.';
        die();
    }
```

what is my problem !

Comment: Could you post here what you put to `$checkmail` ?

Comment: $checkmail = filtermail('big.ma3ih@gmail.com');

Comment: Well if you put this into that function. it will return TRUE, which, if you write it with echo will output 1. Could you explain what you expect from this function and what do you need it for ?

Comment: so why if($checkmail == 'false2'){
  echo 'ایمیل www ندارد.';
  die();
 } this code run? i just dont want users put www. in emails cuz half of them do this for email :|

Comment: You can see that echo when running that function ?

Comment: It can be a good thing to do if('false2' == $checkmail) as this will prevent you accidentally assigning 'false2' to $checkmail by accidentally using a single = instead of ==.  This doesn't solve your problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using filter_var with the given email, you get back your email address ([Test here](http://www.functions-online.com)). This should result in true in your first if condition. The explode should return an array with 1 element at the key 0. So your second condition results in false and so the else is working and return true.

Update:
Your Problem is $checkmail is set to true, your condition compares a bool value with a string value, so the string value is converted to a bool value, wich results in this case in true. Change your condition to : if ( $mailcheck === 'false2' ){ ...

Comment: It would be better to use strpos to find www. in your string. So explode is required to parse the whole string, wich takes more time.

Comment: Your Problem is $checkmail is set to true, your condition compares a bool value with a string value, so the string value is converted to a bool value, wich results in this case in true.

Change your condition to :
if ( $mailcheck === 'false2' ){ ...

Comment: like ! its work butzi plz put it in answer for choose best answer